# Going back to home page on refreshing/reloading or manually entering the URL in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am a beginner and trying to build a website using react.
I created something similar to local:3000/University with the help of the code below

```
<div>
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/University" component={University}/>
        <Redirect to="/University" />
    </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

I then used a button to direct to the localhost:3000/University. However on refreshing the page or entering the URL manually, I find myself at the home page even though the url still says 
localhost:3000/University.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "I find myself at the home page"? The code you provided should always redirect you to the "/University" route and render the `University` component no matter what the URL was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you must to use Switch with Redirect in this case.
See the code

```js
<div>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>      
      <Route path="/University" component={University}/>
      <Redirect to="/University" />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

From documentation

> Switch -
>   Renders the first child  or  that matches the
>   location.

As a result you have infinity count of redirects and you component University doesn't render